# don't understand why i'm not changing my php variable with my script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to teach myself how to use AJAX with PHP.  However, I am unable to get my (likely broken) AJAX code to change the value of my $things variable.  Instead, what happens is the index.php page gets reloaded and a brand new button gets added.  Here is my code:

```
<?php
      $things = 0;
?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>testing</title>
    <script>
    function changeMe()
    {
       var xmlhttp;

       if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
       {
          xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       }

       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
       {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
          {
             document.getElementById("changetest").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
       }

       var things = "<?php echo $things; ?>";

       things++;

       xmlhttp.open("GET","index.php?things="+things,true);
       xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
      echo "<p>Things = <span id=\"changetest\"" . $things . "</span></p>";
    ?>
    <button type="button" onclick="changeMe()">Change Content</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Any clue as to where I'm messing up?

Comment: aren't you missing a `>` like: `echo "<p>Things = <span id=\"changetest\">" . $things . "</span></p>";`

Comment: if you just go to index.php?things=1 do you see the response you expect?

Comment: When you call index things is initialized as 0, when you pass the new things in the GET of this ajax it doesn't mean anything to that variable, so the `var things = php` is always starting out as 0. At the top of the page where $things = 0; have it look for a param like `$_GET['things']` and set it = to that. The problem then is, that'll only really work once. Your ajax is basically trying to load the same page without know what the previous state of things was before it because you don't send any new data, no thing gets updated and nothing changes so it'll keep redoing the same things again.

Comment: I think you are mixing up php and js. `things !== $things` !!! And you are not reading anything from the request, in php `$things` will always be 0 (as you hardcode it on the first line), you should probably use something like `$things = $_GET['things']`

Comment: Why are you doing the `<p>...</p>` in php?  Why don't you just `echo $things;` like you did previously?

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two problems I can see:

- You are not using the variable you are sending back to the server `$_GET['things']` anywhere. Instead you are always setting it to `0` so you will never see anything else;
- You are posting to the original php file. That means that the response will be the complete html page, including the `head`, etc. You probably want a separate file to only send back what you really need.

An example of a separate php file would just be to echo out what was sent in:

```
<?php
echo 'I sent the number: ' . intval($_GET['things']);
```

And now you should make an ajax request to this file and not `index.php`.

Comment: What would be the proper way to update the value on the same page?  That is my original intent.

Comment: @user2081785 Ajax is the right way when you need information from the server. What exactly do you need from the server and what do you store there (and how)? If you don't need any interaction with the server, plain javascript is all you need.

Comment: my goal is to have php echo the value of a variable to the page, someone click a button to either increase or decrease that value, and have the originating php page reflect that new value.  Then I can later submit that new value to a database.  I'm thinking I need to employ SESSION variables, but I don't know how to do that with AJAX yet.

Comment: @user2081785 An ajax request is a normal request so you can use session variables in php like you would normally do. But if the variables are just temporarily stored until you send them to a database, why do you need the server at all? You can store the information in javascript / localstorage or whatever and just make a request to the server when you need it.

Comment: Ah, totally forgot about trying html local storage.  I'll look into that.  So I guess that I could just use a regular innerHtml javascript function to write the updated value to the screen in real-time, and use the local html storage until I submit to the db.  Am I on the right track with that?

Comment: @user2081785 I don't know your exact use-case but that sounds about what I would do.

Answer (score -3):

You should remove the quotes around `"<?php echo $things; ?>";` and make it `var things = <?php echo "'".$things."'"; ?>` instead.

Comment: That doesn't change anything.

Comment: I'm not sure why he'd want his JS variable of things to literally equal <?php echo $things; ?> as a string - not just the value of the php variable $things.

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII: your code is just changing "0" to '0'.  Makes no difference.

Comment: My mistake, I thought the `<?php .. ?>` in quotes would be interpreted as part of the JS string.